# Serialize Selected Properties from Class Collection

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

In C#, I have a collection class (`FeatureCollection`) in which I want to serialize to JSON and return it to the caller. The `Feature` class contains 5 properties but the caller needs only 2. Since I'm well concerned about the response time and performance, and since I aim to minimize the size of the data I'm sending, I was wondering whether there is a way to send a 'minimized' version of the collection (after trimming the undesired properties) without manually implementing a new minimized class. The reason why I don't like to create a new minimized class and map it to the original class is just to keep my code dry and clean.

The code I think of (which is obviously not working) would look like the following:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myFeatureCollection.TrimProperties(typeof(Feature).GetProperties().ToList().Find(property => property.Name == "Property1" || property.Name == "property2")));
```

Comment: This is covered in the Json.Net documentation: [Reducing Serialized JSON Size](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/ReducingSerializedJSONSize.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using Json.NET, you can use the [`JsonIgnore`](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size) attribute:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I'll mark this as answer. However, do you know if I can specify `[JsonIgnore]` on runtime?

Comment: Never mind, it's here: http://blog.mariusschulz.com/2013/04/15/conditionally-serializing-fields-and-properties-with-jsonnet

Answer (score 2):

Would using an Anonymous type work for you?

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myFeatureCollection.Select(x => new { x.Property1, x.Property2 }));
```